# How to redirect ls output into `less -R` if the output size is large

Tags: zsh, ls, less

If the count of `ls` output is more than 20 could it be redirected into `less -R`, in order the keep the bash clean. If its less than 20, the output could printed into the terminal.

When I do `ls` for example in `/home/user/` folder and if there over 200 files all their names are printed out into the terminal.

In case if its over 200, or based on the height of the terminal, somehow can we redirect the results into `less -R` and let after pressing `q` in `less` keep the terminal clean.

I have tried following solution but right after I press `q` in `less` the printed outputs remain in the terminal.

---

my setup, please note that I am using `zsh` shell:

```
export PAGER="less"
export LESS="-iR -j4 --shift 5 -P ?n?f%f .?m(file %i of %m) ..?ltlines %lt-%lb?L/%L. :byte %bB?s/%s. .?e(END) ?x- Next\: %x.:?pB%pB\%..%t"

function ls {
    output=$(command ls -h --color=always -v --author --time-style=long-iso -C | wc -l)
    if [ $output -gt 20 ]; then
        command ls -h --color=always -v --author --time-style=long-iso -C "$@" | less -R
    else
        command ls -h --color=always -v --author --time-style=long-iso -C "$@" | less -R -F -X
    fi
}

alias ls='ls -h --color=always -v --author --time-style=long-iso'
```

---

Comment: If you want the filenames to disappear after pressing `q`, remove the `-X` option from `less`. Also remove the `fi`. And I am not sure why you need PAGER and the alias.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks. I have removed `-X`. But now `ls` does not print anything if its output is small, it just blinks. If I don't have the alias `ls`'s output is not printed in color

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the easiest way to solve this kind of thing, is to simply pass `less` the `-F` flag, which make `less` exit immediately, if the entire file fits on a single terminal screen. You can make `less` always use the `-F` flag, by adding it to the `$LESS` environment variable. For example, you could add this to your `.zprofile` file:

```bsh
export LESS='-F'
```

Comment: I was having something like: `export LESS="-iR -j4 --shift 5 -P ?n?f%f .?m(file %i of %m) ..?ltlines
%lt-%lb?L/%L. :byte %bB?s/%s. .?e(END) ?x- Next\: %x.:?pB%pB\%..%t"
` can I combine it with `-F`?

Comment: I think the best way to answer that is to just try it. 

Comment: Should I keep `export` inside `.zprofile`? I was keeping them inside `.zshenv`

Comment: As I remember `-F` works as you mentioned but it dumps the output in the terminal after less is closed, like its output remains in the terminal

Comment: You should not put `export`s inside `.zshenv`, because that file gets sourced for _every_ shell instance, incl. non-interactive subshells. Doing too much in `.zshenv` can thus drastically reduce your shell’s performance.

Comment: `.zprofile`, on the other hand, is sourced only for login shells. A login shell is the first shell you open in a new remote connection or terminal window/tab. All other shells are descendants of a login shell and each shell automatically imports all env vars on startup. Therefore, it’s enough to `export` your env vars just once: in the login shell, in `.zprofile`.

Comment: `export LESS='-F'` is not read from `.zprofile` and other exports like `LESS_TERMCAP_mb` through on my ssh connections  I have to recarry all exports into `.zshenv`

Comment: The first shell you open through an `ssh` connection should always be a login shell: https://linuxhandbook.com/login-shell/

Comment: I understand but on top of login shell, when I disconnect and re-connect into it using ssh; the `exports` that are defined in `.zprofile` is not detected from the new session I am in. When I do `echo $LESS` it returns empty output and so on

Comment: You do realize that your `export`s need to be in `.zprofile` _on the remote machine_ you are connecting to, right? Your env vars are not transported over `ssh` to your remote shell.

Comment: Yeah I did that like having all my `export`s in the `.zprofile`on the *remote machine*. But the are not seen by my connection sessions. So I carry back all back to `zshenv`.

Comment: Sounds like you're not getting a login shell, then, on your remote server. But for solving that, please open a new question.

Comment: `-F` prevents https://github.com/dandavison/delta to redirect its output into `less -R`, is it possible to prevent it

Comment: Why don’t you post a new question for that?