# Test if a command's output is an empty string and print its results if its not empty

Tags: zsh, test

I am using solutions from [Test if a command outputs an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string). In addition to those solutions, I want to print command's output if its not empty.

I was wondering would it be possible to print command's output if its not empty by calling the command only one time.

I can do it by re-calling the same command inside the `if condition`, but now second call may consume additional CPU usage, since we already obtained its result.

---

Possible approach could be, where the same command is called two times:

```bsh
if [[ $(ls -A) ]]; then
    ls -A
else
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

---

```bsh
output=$(git diff --ignore-blank-lines --color-words HEAD | tr -d ' \n\r\t ' | wc -c)
if [ "$output" -gt 0 ]; then
    git diff --ignore-blank-lines --color-words HEAD 
else
    echo "diff is empty"
fi
```

Comment: Note that for the _specific_ case of checking the number of names in a directory, `ls` is not the best tool for the job. It would be better to `set -- *` (possibly setting `nullglob` and/or `dotglob` in `bash` first) and then look at `"$#"`.

Comment: For the purpose of the question I can remove `ls` section, since it leads another question as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657078/how-to-redirect-ls-output-into-less-r-if-the-output-size-is-large

// For @Stephen Kitt's answer than should we first set `set -- *` ?

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob dotglob; set -- *; [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && echo 'no files'`

Comment: Where can I download `shopt`? // E: Unable to locate package `shopt` // please note that I am using `zsh` shell

Comment: `shopt` is a builtin utility in the `bash` shell. You tagged your question with the [tag:bash] tag.

Comment: Note that this question would have had a _totally_ different set of answers, had you mentioned that you used the `zsh` shell.

Comment: @alper, you're using Zsh, but your question is tagged with [tag:bash] in particular and not [tag:zsh]?

Comment: Technically, the answer to the question in the title, to "check if output is non-empty, and print it if it is", is to just print it unconditionally. Since printing an empty output doesn't do anything. But that's not exactly what you want.

Comment: @ilkkachu I tagged `bash` by mistake by taking tags from the linked related question, and when I realize my mistake it was too late to change it. I am sorry for this.  // In general I was redirecting `ls` or `git diff` results into `less -R`. I just wanted to ignore redirecting into `less -R` if the command's output is empty and do nothing

Comment: Seems you want `git ... | ifne less`

Comment: Can we use `ifne` in zsh shell? @muru

Comment: It's a normal command like any other, so you can use it in any reasonable shell.

Comment: @alper as two answers there say, it's from the `moreutils` package. You'll need to install that package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note:** The question was originally tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but OP has since stated that the shell used is `zsh`. This will invalidate the answer somewhat.

You can store the output of a command in a variable and test if that variable is empty:

```bash
output="$(your_command)"

if [[ -n $output ]]
then
    printf -- "%s\n" "$output"
else
    printf -- "No output\n"
fi
```

The `-n` test will check if `$output` is a non-empty string. If it is, the content of `$output` will be printed. Otherwise, a message that no output was produced will be printed. **Notice** that the quotes around the `"$output"` are necessary.

**Notice also** that (as mentioned by @ilkkachu), trailing newlines will be removed by the command substitution, so if you care about these, a different approach is necessary.

Comment: The opposite of this is `-z`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the output in any case, you can pipe it to `tee` and use that to duplicate the output without running the command again: once to standard output, once to a command which can act on empty input.

For example:

```
ls | tee >([ $(wc -m) -gt 0 ] || echo No output)
```

Note that this only takes care of standard output, so you can end up with “No output” after an error message. You’ll also have to adjust commands accordingly when their output varies depending on whether it’s going to a terminal or not (*e.g.* `ls -C`, or output with colours).

Comment: If the folder is empty it prints `ls`'s output and `No output` right after it. Is it normal?

Comment: What output do you get from `ls` when the folder is empty? It shouldn’t output anything, and then the above adds “No output” as a result...

Comment: Got it. I was trying `ls | tee >([ $(wc -m) -gt 100 ] || echo some_output)` on non-empty folder hoping to get on `some_output` output. But as I understand, if the folder is not empty, it will always print the `ls` output

Comment: Yes, this is an answer to your stated question, “Test if a command's output is an *empty* string”. Solving your other question about piping output to `less` if it’s too long is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Taking `ls -A` as command example, the following will do:

```bash
if ls -A | grep ^; then
   : the output was already written
else
   : no output
fi

if ! ls -A | grep ^; then
   : handle the no-output condition
fi
```

This will also ensure that trailing newlines are preserved in the output.

For the actual case mentioned in this [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657086/test-if-a-commands-output-is-an-empty-string-and-print-its-results-if-its-not-e/657113?noredirect=1#comment1236669_657086) (do not run `less` with an empty output), there's the `-F` ("quit if one screen") option:

```
command ... | less -FXR
```

(you can omit the `X` with newer versions of `less`).